# Hide/Show menu is not working?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have 3 tabs,

```
           1.Invitation tab
           2.Event tab
           3.Groupchat tab  and
```

3 menus in my layout namely,

```
           1.Dropdown menu
           2.create occasion menu
           3.settings menu
```

Atpresent all my tabs display all three menus,But i need to display specific menu on specific tab when it is onclick,for example

```
           1.when ontap "Invitation tab" just show "settings menu" only.
           2.when ontap "Event tab" only shows"create occasion and settings menus"
           3.similarly when ontap "Groupchat tab" only shows"Dropdown and settings menus".
```

I am tried below code but it is not working as i am expected.Please help me how to solve this problem.

```
    public class UserDashBoardActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String TAB_1_TAG = "Invitation";
    private static final String TAB_2_TAG = "Event";
    private static final String TAB_3_TAG = "GroupChat";
    private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private Menu menu;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityContext(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onPause();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        this.menu=menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_dash_board, menu);
        return true;

    }
    private void updateInvitationMenu() {
        MenuItem dropdownMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.dropdown);
        MenuItem occasionMenu=menu.findItem(R.id.create_occasion);
        occasionMenu.setVisible(false);
        dropdownMenu.setVisible(false);

    }
    private void updateEventMenu() {
        MenuItem dropdownMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.dropdown);
        dropdownMenu.setVisible(false);

    }

    private void updateGroupChatMenu() {
        MenuItem eventMenu=menu.findItem(R.id.create_occasion);
        eventMenu.setVisible(false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_dash_board);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Get TabHost Refference
        tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1_TAG).setIndicator("Invitation"), InvitationFragment.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2_TAG).setIndicator("Event"), OccasionFragment.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_3_TAG).setIndicator("GroupChat"), GroupChatFragment.class, null);

        //invitation tab highlighted by default
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange));
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sandal));
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sandal));    

        //onTabChangedListener added for move one tab to others


        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
                if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0) {
                    updateInvitationMenu();
                } else if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 1) {
                    updateEventMenu();
                } else if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 2) {
                    updateGroupChatMenu();
                }
                setTabColor(tabHost);
            }
        });


    }

    //setTabColor method added for highlighting the tabs
    public void setTabColor(FragmentTabHost tabHost) {

        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.scandal));//unselected

        if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==0)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange));//1st tab selected
        else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==1)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange)); //2nd tab selected
        else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==2)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange)); //3rd tab selected
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        // noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.account_settings) {
            Intent userSettingIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityUserSettings.class);
            userSettingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(userSettingIntent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.profile) {
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ImageUploadActivity.class);
            profileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(profileIntent);
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.create_occasion){

                Intent occasionAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OccasionActivity.class);
                // Clears History of Activity
                occasionAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(occasionAct);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Menu code is below,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appmunu="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="ringee.app.com.ringeeapp.UserDashBoard">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/dropdown"
        android:icon="@drawable/dropdown_icon"
        android:title="Dropdown"
        appmunu:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/all"
                android:title="All" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/event"
                android:title="Event" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/invitation"
                android:title="Invitation" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/create_occasion"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_event"
        android:title="Create Occasion"
        appmunu:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/account_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/profile_image" />

</menu>
```

My dashboard layout code is below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ToggleButton btn1, btn2, btn3;
 Menu myMenu;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  btn1 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.option1);
  btn2 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.option2);
  btn3 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.option3);

  btn1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnOnCheckedChangeListener);
  btn2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnOnCheckedChangeListener);
  btn3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnOnCheckedChangeListener);
 }

 OnCheckedChangeListener btnOnCheckedChangeListener =
  new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
     boolean isChecked) {
    if(myMenu != null){
     if(buttonView==btn1){

      myMenu.findItem(R.id.menuopt1)
       .setVisible(isChecked);
      myMenu.findItem(R.id.menuopt1)
       .setEnabled(isChecked);
     }else if(buttonView==btn2){
      myMenu.findItem(R.id.menuopt2)
       .setVisible(isChecked);
      myMenu.findItem(R.id.menuopt2)
       .setEnabled(isChecked);
     }else if(buttonView==btn3){
      myMenu.findItem(R.id.menuopt3)
       .setVisible(isChecked);
      myMenu.findItem(R.id.menuopt3)
       .setEnabled(isChecked);
     }
    }

   }};

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  myMenu = menu;
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch(item.getItemId()){
  case R.id.menuopt1:
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
    "menuopt1", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   break;
  case R.id.menuopt2:
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
    "menuopt2", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   break;
  case R.id.menuopt3:
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
    "menuopt3", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   break;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

}
```

Comment: now i am added my dashboard layout code in that i am using tabwidgets to combine all tabs.So i am not have individual id for each tab ..now i am need to changed each tab as button?

Comment: did u got my message..i need your help

Comment: you will have to do this in Activity where you have added fragment

Comment: can u please see my dashboard layout code in that i am using tabwidget to combined all tabs...in your code you are using toggle button for each tab...now what i want to change on that dashboard layout...